# Search through the array in the searchbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, search

I took [advantage](http://www.pumpmybicep.com/2014/08/18/searching-uitableview-with-uisearchdisplaycontroller/) of this article to create a search in my application. Slightly changed the code for yourself. But if I add to the array of multiple values (1-5), the search is working perfectly, but if you add an array of say 15 value, then an error takes off

```
    2015-05-07 12:24:55.852 gfhfgh[5662:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.138/UITableView.m:5439
2015-05-07 12:24:55.860 gfhfgh[5662:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2e2fdf83 0x38aaeccf 0x2e2fde5d 0x2ecabd5b 0x30c86dff 0xf00b9 0x30c4d8f7 0x30bf4c27 0x30be7c5d 0x30be7ba3 0x30bf41cd 0x30b3a167 0x30be71eb 0x30bc86fd 0x30bc848d 0x30bc9bf5 0x30c7dcc5 0x30d0c011 0x30c36109 0x30d0abcd 0x30d0aaaf 0x30b50037 0x30b4ffd7 0x30b4ffb1 0x30b3b717 0x30b3acfd 0x30b37805 0x30c16f15 0x30d0a91f 0x30b99127 0x30b993e7 0x30c15c17 0x30e9e579 0x30ca0fed 0x30b4c4e3 0x30ef3aed 0x30b13353 0x30b11a9b 0x30b4ad49 0x30b4a66f 0x30b1f8cd 0x30b1df77 0x2e2c920b 0x2e2c86db 0x2e2c6ecf 0x2e231ebf 0x2e231ca3 0x33137663 0x30b7e14d 0xfa1a9 0x38fbbab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

What is the problem?
My code

```
        #import "StreetTableViewController.h"
    @interface StreetTableViewController () 
    //@interface StreetTableViewController () <UISearchDisplayDelegate>
    // the items to be searched

    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *items;

    // the current search results
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *searchResults;

    @end

    @implementation StreetTableViewController

    #pragma mark - NSCoding

    // set some initial searchable items
    - (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
    {
        self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
        if (self) {
            _items
                     = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"bar", @"foo", @"quux",@"bar2", @"foo2", @"quux2",@"bar3", @"foo3", @"quux3",@"bar4", @"foo4", @"quux4",@"bar5", @"foo5", @"quux5",@"bar6", @"foo6", @"quux6",
@"bar7", @"foo7", @"quux7",@"bar8", @"foo8", @"quux8",@"bar9", @"foo9", @"quux9",@"bar10", @"foo10", @"quux10",  nil];
        }
        return self;
    }

    #pragma mark - UISearchDisplayDelegate

    // register a cell reuse identifier for the search results table view
    -(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
     didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
          forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell"];
    }

    // perform the search
    -(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
    shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
        NSPredicate *predicate
        = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self beginswith [c] %@", searchString];
        NSArray *searchResults
        = [[self items] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        [self setSearchResults:searchResults];

        return YES;
    }

    #pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

    // check if displaying search results
    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        if ([[self searchDisplayController] isActive]) {
            return [[self searchResults] count];
        } else {
            return [[self items] count];
        }
    }

    // check if displaying search results
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
            cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if ([[self searchDisplayController] isActive]) {
            UITableViewCell *cell
            = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell"
                                              forIndexPath:indexPath];
            id item = [[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            [[cell textLabel] setText:item];
            return cell;
        } else {
            UITableViewCell *cell
            = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"
                                              forIndexPath:indexPath];
            id item = [[self items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            [[cell textLabel] setText:item];
            return cell;
        }
    }

    #pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

    // manually perform detail segue after selecting a search result
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if ([[self searchDisplayController] isActive]) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSegue" sender:cell];
        }
    }

    #pragma mark - UIViewController

    /* prepare for detail scene segue
     called after cell selection in the master and
     search results table views */
    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;

        id item = nil;
        if ([[self searchDisplayController] isActive]) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath
            = [[[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView] indexPathForCell:cell];
            item = [[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        } else {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath
            = [[self tableView] indexPathForCell:cell];
            item = [[self items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        }

        UIViewController *detail
        = (UIViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        [[detail navigationItem] setTitle:item];
    }
    @end
```

Comment: problem is your identifier name in here how you used means using single tableview or multiple for search

Comment: Cell identifier should be same, in your condition all cell identifier should be `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may understood your problem (or may not...). Check if you wrote the cell identifier (SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell) in your SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell.nib file (or SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell.m file instead).

I think that you didn't reused cells at all. For 5 cells you didn't need that, because the UITableView needed to create 5 cells anyway (the dequeue method create (tableHeight / cellHeight) cells, and all other cell are reused).

Another option, if you registered your class but not your nib file:
add

`[self.yourTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell" bundle:nil]
             forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell"];`

Comment: it work if i do like this `- (void) viewDidLoad{ [super viewDidLoad]; [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell"]; } `